# Можете обьяснить пожалуйста как работает этот код Css анимаци

Tags: css, css3, css-animation

Немного понимаю но все таки сложновато понять как работает код

Спасибо большое кто обьяснит.

```
.headtext:before{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: orange;
    visibility: hidden;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    
}
.headtext:hover:before{
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

Comment: На базовом элементе (псевдоэлементе `:before`) объявлен `transition` с характеристиками "плавного изменения значения". Для этого же элемента в состоянии `:hover` (при наведении на родителя) происходит изменение свойства `transform` `scaleX`, в результате чего, из-за `transition`, происходит его плавное изменение с изначального значения на новое.

Comment: Еще вопрос зачем указывать ```content: "";``` если его и так там нету

Comment: Чтобы дать псевпоэлементу "вещественности". По умолчанию `content` не назначен. Пустая строка — это уже какое-то назначенное значение

Comment: Это обязательно делать?

Comment: @Half, без content псевдоэлемент работать не будет

Comment: visibility, кстати, абсолютно лишнее свойство тут - оно ни на что не влияет

Comment: ```bottom: 0;``` ```left: 0;``` как работает ```bottom```, ```left``` я знаю как с лева направо а вот как он не знаю

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. `transform: scaleX(0)` сжимает Ваш псевдоэлемент по оси Х с двух сторон до нулевого значения.
2. `transform: scaleX(1)` при наведении придаёт ему исходный размер (т.е. `width: 100%`).
3. Благодаря `transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s` это изменение происходит плавно, получается как бы анимация (хотя на самом деле css-анимация - это другое).
4. `visibility: hidden/visible` не играет никакой роли, так что это свойство можно смело убирать из кода

```css
.headtext {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
.headtext:before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: orange;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    
}
.headtext:hover:before{
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="headtext">наведи на меня курсор</div>
```

Comment: Еще вопрос как работает ```bottom: 0``` и зачем оно там я знаю что ```left``` делает анимацию слево направо а ```right``` наоборот

Comment: @Half, bottom: 0 располагает Ваш псевдоэлемент внизу родительского блока. Вот я сейчас в своём примере изменил это правило - сделал top: 0. Если Вы запустите код, то увидите, что псевдоэлемент переместился наверх.

Comment: @Half, насчёт left и right: к направлению анимации эти свойства отношения не имеют. Они влияют на расположение абсолютно спозиционированного элемента. Другое дело, что в Вашем случае при width: 100% никакой разницы нет - псевдоэлемент и так в ширину от края до края, т.е. у него и left: 0, и right: 0. А вот если бы ширина была не 100%, то эти значения уже влияли бы на положение псевдоэлемента.

Comment: Спасибо большое.